# How to get the parent items in datagridview

Tags: c#, logic

I have datagridview that has 5 columns `[ID, Code, Name, Desc, ParentID]`

data is of 3 levels `(Country, State, City)`

Example of the data

```
ID  Code  Name       Desc             ParentID
15  A31   Canada     Frams, Water     0
16  J83   Ontario    Cars, Farms      15
17  K76   Alberta    Water            15
18  K24   Toronto    Fish, People     16
19  W83   Ottawa     Cars, Air        16
20  S74   Australia  Farms, People    0
21  W11   Victoria   Buses, Cars      20
22  K39   Melbourne  Fish, Sky        21
```

I filter datagridview based on Desc as following

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("Desc like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

This is working fine.

But if user was searching for Desc = "Fish"

in that case the grid will only show Toronto and Melbourne.

```
ID  Code  Name       Desc             ParentID
18  K24   Toronto    Fish, People     16
22  K39   Melbourne  Fish, Sky        21
```

I want to have all the hierarchy upward with that search

I mean I want to show Parent of Toronto Which is Ontario and the parent of Ontario which is Canada

Similarly for Melbourne -> Victoria -> Australia

So my grid will show these records

```
ID  Code  Name       Desc             ParentID
15  A31   Canada     Frams, Water     0
16  J83   Ontario    Cars, Farms      15
18  K24   Toronto    Fish, People     16
20  S74   Australia  Farms, People    0
21  W11   Victoria   Buses, Cars      20
22  K39   Melbourne  Fish, Sky        21
```

How to do that in the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up to get the result you need:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource mainSource = new BindingSource();
        mainSource.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        mainSource.Filter = string.Format("Desc like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'");

        BindingSource resultSource = new BindingSource();

        getParents(mainSource, resultSource);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = resultSource;
    }
```

To get the parents of the initial result it can be achieve this and can recursively get the parents.

```
private void getParents(BindingSource mainSource, BindingSource resultSource)
    {
        List<int> parentIdList = new List<int>();

        foreach (var item in mainSource.List)
        {
            resultSource.List.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (DataRowView item in mainSource.List)
        {
            parentIdList.Add((int)item.Row["ParentId"]);
        }

        if (parentIdList.Count > 0)
        {
            var parentIdCSV = string.Join(",", parentIdList);
            mainSource.Filter = string.Format("Id IN ({0})", parentIdCSV);
            getParents(mainSource, resultSource);
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps you. Happy coding.